# How to change database schema in Celery task?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a middleware that changes database schema depending on subdomain:

```
def tenant_schema_from_request(request):
    hostname = hostname_from_request(request)
    tenants_map = get_tenants_map()
    return tenants_map.get(hostname)

def set_tenant_schema_for_request(request):
    schema = tenant_schema_from_request(request)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SET search_path to {}".format(schema))

class TenantMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        set_tenant_schema_for_request(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

but how to change database schema in Celery task?

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def send_notification_task(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [.using](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset)

```
Author.objects.using('default').all()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but it's for selecting database, not schema or I'm wrong?

Comment: You need to define multiple databases in your settings pointing to the same DB. In the config you can add options for that db to use when queried. This is where you will add your "search_path" to. I will edit my answer above in a min.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I ran into the exact same issue and found a solution. Sharing it in case someone else needs it.

You should use a celery `task_prerun` signal to switch the active schema before the task runs.

Here's an example that switches the current schema to the public schema before the task runs.

```
from celery.signals import task_prerun
from django.db import connection

# ensure the task always runs on the public schema
@task_prerun.connect(sender=send_notification_task)
def activate_public_schema(sender, **kwargs):
    connection.schema_name = 'public'

@shared_task
def send_notification_task(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    ...
```